# Codeigniter database issue

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

Having a spot of bother trying to grab some data out of my database.

I have the following model:

```
function GetRestaurants($options = array())
    {
        // Qualification
        if(isset($options['restaurantID']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantID', $options['restaurantID']);
        if(isset($options['restaurantRegionID']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantRegionID', $options['restaurantRegionID']);
        if(isset($options['restaurantName']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantName', $options['restaurantName']);
        if(isset($options['restaurantAddress1']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantAddress1', $options['restaurantAddress1']);
        if(isset($options['restaurantAddress2']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantAddress2', $options['restaurantAddress2']);
        if(isset($options['restaurantSuburb']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantSuburb', $options['restaurantSuburb']);
        if(isset($options['restaurantCity']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantCity', $options['restaurantCity']);
        if(isset($options['restaurantInformation']))
            $this->db->where('restaurantInformation', $options['restaurantInformation']);

        // limit / offset
        if(isset($options['limit']) && isset($options['offset']))
            $this->db->limit($options['limit'], $options['offset']);
        else if(isset($options['limit']))
            $this->db->limit($options['limit']);

        // sort
        if(isset($options['sortBy']) && isset($options['sortDirection']))
            $this->db->order_by($options['sortBy'], $options['sortDirection']);

        $query = $this->db->get("tblRestaurants");

        if(isset($options['count'])) return $query->num_rows();

        if(isset($options['restaurantID']))
            return $query->row(0);

        if(isset($options['limit']) && $options['limit'] == '1')
            return $query->row(0);

        return $query->result();
    }
```

Now the following code works fine:

```
$this->load->model('Restaurants_model');
        $data['restaurant'] =  $this->Restaurants_model->GetRestaurants(array(
            'restaurantName' => 'shed 5', 
            'limit' => '1'
            ));
```

However the following does not work:

```
$this->load->model('Restaurants_model');
        $data['restaurant'] =  $this->Restaurants_model->GetRestaurants(array(
            'restaurantName' => str_replace('-', ' ', $this->uri->segment(2)), 
            'limit' => '1'
            ));
```

Even though the result of

```
str_replace('-', ' ', $this->uri->segment(2))
```

is in this instance: ‘shed 5’.

I have compared var_dumps of the output of the str_replace and the string itself and determined them to be identical. So why does the straight string return a result yet the string generated from the uri segment doesn’t? Some kind of encoding issue? My database holds data in ‘utf8_general_ci’.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Have a look what the difference in the output of echo $this->db->last_query() is. This helps most of the time with query problems. Insert it in your model after $query = $this->db->get("tblRestaurants");

Answer (score 0):

$restaurant=str_replace('-', ' ', $this->uri->segment(2));

get value outside array and try array_push

$data['restaurant'] =  $this->Restaurants_model->GetRestaurants(array(
            'restaurantName' => $restaurant, 
            'limit' => '1'
            ));